# Why do I need .length to find the equivalence of array elements in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, indexing

The problem I'm working on iterates over an array but has three distinct behaviors depending on where in the array I am:
1. The last element: do A;
2. The second to last element: do B;
3. All other elements: do C.

To identify my position, I was using if statements, and noticed that my if statements do not evaluate as expected when I simply use an index of [-1] and [-2]. Why?

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if (arr[i] === arr[arr.length-1]){console.log(`last itme`)} // This one evaluates i to be equal to the last item in the array when i is length-1
  if (arr[i] === arr[-1]){console.log(`last itme`)} // This one *does not* evaluates i to be equal to the last item in the array when i is length-1
}
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate - I did search and couldn't find anything that looked similar. Thanks!

Comment: Because `-1` is not a valid array index.

Comment: An array is a list of items, say `[1,2,3]`; which one of those is the "negative first"?

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes in JS are defined as

> A String [property name](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#property-name) P is an *[array index](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#array-index)* if and only if [ToString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tostring)([ToUint32](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-touint32)(P)) is P and [ToUint32](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-touint32)(P) is not (2<sup>32</sup> − 1).

(effectively it means integers in the [0; 2<sup>32</sup> − 1) range)

So negative indexes like −1, while they could be useful, just do not exist.

References:

- https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-array-exotic-objects

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays indexes start at 0. Values like -1 or -2 are not vaild indexes in JS.

(Maybe you have a pythonic background because it means something in python.)

Comment: Thanks Arash! Saying I have a "background" feels generous considering how new I am to programming generally, but I did start with Python - so maybe that's where I picked it up!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it makes sense to move the if statements out of the loop as with your current code you would get some funny behaviour with arrays like:

```
 [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

as it will enter both ifs all the time.  So instead you could do:

```
 if(arr.length > 0) {
   const last = arr[arr.length - 1];
   //...
 }

 if(arr.length > 1) {
  const second = arr[arr.length - 2];
  //...
 }

 for(const rest of arr.slice(0, -2)) {
   //...
 }
```